# Error:(2, 0) Plugin with id 'android-apt' not found

Tags: android, gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'android-apt'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.android.booklistingapp"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
      testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:+'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.4.0'

}
```

Comment: It still gives error "Error:(26, 0) Could not find method apt() for arguments [com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.4.0] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler."

Comment: sorry check http://stackoverflow.com/a/39458390/3395198

Comment: Did you solved this yet ?

Answer (score 3):

Add these lines in the build.gradle file in the root directory of your Android Studio project.

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8'
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to add the classpath for the `android-apt` plugin:

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    mavenCentral()
   }
  dependencies {
    classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8'
  }
}
```

In the dependencies you need also the apt dependency for the compiler:

```
dependencies {
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:+'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.4.0'
    // Add this
    apt 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.4.0'
}
```